# When updating to Magento 2.3.1 db_schema.xml is invalid: Element 'schema': No matching global declaration available for the validation root

Tags: database, magento2.3, declarative-schema

While updating **Magento 2.2.8 to 2.3.1**

I'm facing issue when running `bin/magento setup:upgrade`

I get error:

```
The XML in file "/var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-store/etc/db_schema.xml" is invalid:
Element 'schema': No matching global declaration available for the validation root.
Line: 9
```

**Anyone was facing this kind of issues?**

Comment: Same problem here, though the file *magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd* is present in vendors.
Cache cleaned as well.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/155718)

Comment: None of these fixes worked for me. I upgraded from 2.1.7 to 2.3.1.
I have cleared cache. The xsd file exists.
Any other ideas anyone?

Answer (score 4):

Check if any of your custom module has overridden any xsd file or SchemaLocator class. Comment that override and run the setup:upgrade again.

We got the same issue and found that our custom module had a plugin on below class:
Magento\Framework\Config\SchemaLocator. We commented this plugin in di.xml file and the issue is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that the `schema.xsd` file that controls the URN schema validation for the new `db_schema.xml` files is either missing or you have not cleared the cache.

First, try removing all folders and files inside the `var/cache` folder and run the `bin/magento setup:upgrade` command again. It that doesn’t solve the issue, check that you have correctly upgraded all Magento files by checking if the following file is present in your installation:

```
vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd
```

If that file is missing, you will have to try upgrading again your Magento installations. If you are using the downloaded zip package, just copy again the files and be sure to replace the existing files in your installation by the new ones. If you are using composer, follow these instructions: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html